# MySQL Cursor Loop Returns Nothing Even For Simplest Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to MySQL stored procedures.
I have this below MySQL stored procedure, here I define a cursor, loop throug the query results and concat the results into a string. The problem is my string is always returned as null no matter what I do. Can you tell me what the problem is?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_findUsers`(in userid int)
BEGIN

DECLARE c_rowcount int default 0;
DECLARE c_finished INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE my_uid INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE user_list VARCHAR(65535) DEFAULT ""; /*varchar max*/

DECLARE c_cursor CURSOR FOR select userID from mydb.mytable;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET c_finished = 1;

OPEN c_cursor;
set c_rowcount = found_rows();
getuserIDs : LOOP
FETCH c_cursor INTO my_uid;
IF c_finished = 1 THEN
LEAVE getuserIDs;
END IF;
SET user_list = CONCAT(my_uid,user_list);
END LOOP getuserIDs;

CLOSE c_cursor;
set c_finished = 0;
select @user_list;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed "debugger for MySQL" and checked the values for the variables/parameters step by step. It looked like the procedure was working correctly. The problem is simple and stupid :)
On the last line, instead of "select @user_list" I should have written "select user_list". As soon as I removed the @ symbol it worked like a charm.
MySQL version 5.6.17.